# Microsoft Excel Data Validation

Tags: excel

I have a excel sheet and i have created a data validation function. Its a conditional dropdown but I can not input my equation in data validation field. Its says too many arguments. My equation is `=IF(A4="Capital",'New List'!$C$2:$C$42,IF(A4="Pier Caps",'New List'!$C$43:$C$84),IF(A4="Keystones",'New List'!$C$85:$C$86),IF(A4="Round Louvre",'New List'!$C$87:$C$88),IF(A4="Open Rings",'New List'!$C$89:$C$90),IF(A4="Pyramids",'New List'!$C$91:$C$92),IF(A4="Plinths",'New List'!$C$93:$C$94),IF(A4="Columns",'New List'!$C$95:$C$96))`

What i am missing here? Is it too long? Is there any other way to achieve this?

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: Does the formula work in a worksheet cell?

Comment: Yes. It works in other cells. But whenever i try to put it in data validation window its says too many arguments.

Comment: I believe there is a maximum length for formulas in data validation of 255 characters. Your formula exceeds that.

Comment: Can I replace that equation with something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create individual named ranges for each of your lists. For example the range

`Capital` refers to `'New List'!$C$2:$C$42`

`Pier_Caps` refers to `'New List'!$C$43:$C$84`

etc. Note that there cannot be spaces in named ranges. Use the underscore _ character instead. Now you can use this in the data validation:

```
=INDIRECT(SUBSTITUTE($A$4," ","_"))
```

In words: Take cell A4, replace any spaces with underscores and return the range with that name.